# Web Development - Flask and Database connection

Tags: python, sql, database, web

I am building a small web-app based on Flask. I want to make a web-page, which will show some data taken from a database. This database is filed with data from some internet resources. The data in this database should be updated every 30 sec, which means I am sending update requests every 30 sec.

The way of how I see it's working:

1). script_db.py gets data from web and puts it in the database and updates database every 30 sec.

2). script_main.py gets the updated data from the database and renders the HTML template.

Question:

I want script_db.py to be executed automatically in the background, so that script_main.py will always have access to the most updated data.

1). The way I see it, is it the best way to work with the database, which needs to be automatically updated?

2). How to run that script_db.py in a background and then start script_main.py, whenever I want?

Thank You

Disclaimer: I am totally new to what I am trying to do. Any suggestion would help.

Comment: If it's just going to be one webpage, and you want to save the data in the database for use later, you could have javascript running on the page which is on a 30 second timer to issue a json request to a route on your server which retrieves the data, stores it in your database, and then returns the data to your javascript json request.

Comment: @Chockomonkey Thank You for your reply! I have never used JavaScript. Can I do what I want without JS?

Comment: When there's a will there's a way :) Unfortunately I've never implemented timed requests in pure flask, so hopefully someone else can chime in with experience on that. To start though, I would say that you'll likely have the code from your hypothetical script_db.py and script_main.py files represented in flask routes, so that you can trigger them.. ie website.com/fetch_data/ contains code to request the data from the web API and updates the db. Then you could have another route which simply displays the data, ie website.com/dashboard/.

Comment: I would recommend using Javascript in your html template as well to make requests to the flask server every 30 seconds. This would only be a few lines of code. You could also just reload of the page every 30 second with some HTML code. The feature you want i.e. the Flask server updating the HTML template by itself without anyone requesting it, would be possible only with a websocket which would require you to write complicated Javascript code on the webpage. Requesting or reloading the page every 30 seconds is far more simpler.